# Jersey multipart getFileName() has concatenated path

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to get a file upload working with Java + Jersey + multipart + Tomcat + HTML/CSS/JS.

For testing purposes I'm just trying to upload some arbitrary file from my Downloads folder and have it written to my desktop.

My only problem seems to be that when I try to get the filename of the uploaded file via `fileDetail.getFileName();` somehow I'm getting a concatenated path in with the filename ("C:UsersHackRDownloadsstackexample.csv").

My plan (following a tutorial) was to then prepend the destination directory to the filename:

```
    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/Users/HackR/Desktop/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();
```

and write it out. However it ends up trying to write it to somethings like this:

```
C:/Users/HackR/Desktop/C:UsersHackRDownloadsstackexample.csv
```

which actually just creates a 0kb file named `C` on my desktop.

How can I get the actual filename the way I need it for this example (i.e. no path)?

This is my entire file upload service:

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "C:/Users/HackR/Desktop/"
                + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe mention on which exact platform you are? Windows 10? Because that will make it easier to find the source of your problem, which I guess originates in your system's browser engine that is used by eclipse :)

Comment: @yeoman Yes, it's Windows 10, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenated file name is a result of using the browser internal to Eclipse, which may not properly support your HTML, CSS, JS, etc, especially if you're using Angular JS or any webkit technologies, even indirectly.

The eclipse internal browser is really just a native browser control :) On a Mac, that makes it use Safari, the engine of which is webkit.

Make your work with Safari, or maybe with Chrome, which is still very similar because it's based on a relatively recent fork of webkit, then it should work in the eclipse internal browser on a Mac, too :)

As your post suggests that you're on a Windows machine, you need to instead make your code work with your installed Internet Explorer, because that's what eclipse uses on Windows.

Good luck in any case!

Comment: Thank you. I believe that your answer is referring to the original title of my question. I apologize for this. That title was from an unpublished question I wrote yesterday and it did not correspond to this question. I have fixed the title. Again, my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, much better! :D

Comment: OK so I didn't think this had anything to do with webkit or the browser, but it turns out you're right -- it does. This problem only happens with the stupid internal browser. It doesn't happen with Chrome. I am surprised because I'm just using plain HTML in the file upload page, except that I've used CSS to style the upload button and I use Angular JS to display errors.  Oh, I guess because there are some webkit-filter CSS statements in my styles.css file that must somehow mess up the internal Eclipse browser (Internet Explorer).

Comment: such a classic. so unfortunate because a usable internal browser would actually be a great thing :)